# Array formula skipping blanks, importing adjacent cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to automate simple tasks in my google sheets accounts:
(Link to sheet:[here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12d3F_4TTom5TQTHlG6ilORBu0q9DFKOnO7Bvyv8x6o8/edit?usp=sharing))

I would like all transactions under "Money In" in "Bank Statement" to automatically be entered into "Cash In" with the Descriptions, amounts and payment method carrying over. Similarly, I would like all transactions under "Money Out" in "Bank Statement" to be entered into "Cash Out" with the descriptions, amounts and payment method carrying over. Any help as to how this could be achieved would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 updated it to clarify question and provide link, cheers

Comment: sheet is private, pls share it

Comment: @player0 my mistake, I have set it to public now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your approach to the problem given the formula you're using. It seems to me that what you're asking should be a simple FILTER or QUERY, e.g.:

```
=FILTER(Bank!A4:B, Bank!B4:B<>"")
```

As player0 states, we don't know much without seeing your sheet and data, however. Theoretically, the above formula placed in Accounts!A4 (or A1, A2, A3) would do what you're describing, given that the range A4:B were previously blank.

UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS AND SHEET:

Formulas in place:

```
=FILTER({'Bank Statement'!A3:B,'Bank Statement'!D3:D,'Bank Statement'!C3:C},'Bank Statement'!D3:D<>"",'Bank Statement'!E3:E="")

=FILTER({'Bank Statement'!A3:B,'Bank Statement'!E3:E,'Bank Statement'!C3:C},'Bank Statement'!E3:E<>"",'Bank Statement'!D3:D="")
```

This could have been done with a QUERY as well. But this may be easiest for you to understand. The setup between the curly brackets is a virtual array, which allows choosing the order of the columns. The two parts outside the curly brackets set the conditions (which are opposite depending on the page).

Comment: Hi Erik, I have clarified my question and linked the google sheets document. Thanks for the response, hope this clears it up.

Comment: Your sheet is "Access Denied." Please be sure to set sharing permission to "Anyone with the link can edit."

Comment: Your sheet permission is now set to "View Only." Please carefully read the instructions: Set your permission to "Anyone with the link can edit." I myself will likely not be able to check back again today. Maybe someone else will jump in and help you, once you set the permission correctly.

Comment: Updated again. Apologies for the multiple screw-ups, I did not know the convention when posting, it's the first time I've done so to do with google sheets. Hopefully they will, thanks for your time in responding thus far, really appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like you've seen my updated answer and that it worked for you. Thank you for following through and marking the answer as "Best Answer" so that A.) others here know the issue is resolved and B.) others who may search in the future can easily find working answers for issues similar to their own.